# Resolve Project Problems in NetBeans IDE(ConnectingDataBase)

Tags: java, database, netbeans-8.2

[A Bunch of Problems-Screenshot !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI6Ol.png)

I installed NetBeans.I am seeing a lot of errors under 'Resolve Project Problems' window.I don't know why is this the case.It is showing under the Connecting DataBase folder of which I have no clue of.Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The "Resolve Project Problems" dialog is presenting information that it cannot run the program because required supporting libraries are not present in the project setup.

If you expand your "ConnectingDataBase" Libraries folders, odds are that none of these libraries are present.

My guess as to how you got into this state is that you added a needed library; but, that needed library required many other libraries to "support" the library you needed.

There are a number of ways to fix this, but they all depend on a root cause which is not known.

1. If the project previously worked, looking at the last change might make obvious what part of the project was reconfigured.  Setting the configuration back could be a solution, or moving the existing elements into the new configuration location could be a solution.
2. If the project is relatively new, and something was added, you need to either revert the addition or add the supporting libraries.

There are many ways to add supporting libraries, and a few systems that will do so for you.  I recommend Apache's Maven, but it has a high learning curve.

Comment: So how do I resolve it with Maven ? Will it automatically add it ? Can you please give a clue as to how to get it sorted ?I installed netbeans twice and it showed the same error.My system has both oracle and mySQL.Is it related to it ?

Comment: @whitebull13 In Netbeans, "New Project" > "Maven" > "Java Application" and after the project exists, Dependencies > "Add Dependency".  In the form "Group Id" = "hibernate", "Artifact" = "hibernate", and "version" = "3.0.5".  If you wait till the status in the lower right hand corner finished, then the form will help by auto-completing.  Note that one day, you should read about Apache Maven because you won't be able to find someone who will work this out for each different way you might need to use Maven.